# Calling perl script from Make

Tags: perl, makefile

I have a perl script that generates an index of some data stored in a text file.

I have a make file with a target called buildData that runs the perl script

I have a make file in the parent directory with the following target:

```
data :
    make -C Data buildData
```

if I call

```
make data
```

then I get the message

```
make: 'data' is up to date.
```

but if I call

```
make -C Data buildData
```

then the perl script runs correctly. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you have a file called "data" in there? Or could this be Windows, and it's getting confused with the "Data" directory?

Try adding this pseudo-dependency:

```
.PHONY: data
```

It should tell make to make "data" unconditionally.